# Where is Dojo lightweight (3.8kb) AMD loader?

Tags: javascript, dojo

According to Dojo feature list, there is very small 4K sized loader.

If i use standard

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

then downloaded *dojo.js* is *41 869 bytes* long (noted in about Page dialog box).

I could not find any example using this small loader, everybody seems including *dojo.js*

Comment: *everybody seems including dojo.js* Are you sure?

Comment: I think this page might be useful : http://jamesthom.as/blog/2012/08/03/finding-nano/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That small AMD loader needs to be build by end developer from dojotoolkit sources. Dojo 1.9 beta contains profile needed for building, but still does not ship minimized dojo.js.